# How to get the names of browse widget used in a screen using progress 4gl

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have two browse widget in my screen. I want to get the names of the browse widget through the code. Is it possible ? If possible then how?

I tried LIST-WIDGETS function but it did't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
DEFINE VARIABLE hFrame      AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hFieldGroup AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hWidget     AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN hFrame      = {&window-name}:FIRST-CHILD .

DO WHILE VALID-HANDLE (hFrame):
    
    ASSIGN hFieldGroup = hFrame:FIRST-CHILD 
           hWidget     = hFieldGroup:FIRST-CHILD . 
           
    DO WHILE VALID-HANDLE (hWidget):
        IF hWidget:TYPE = "BROWSE" THEN 
            MESSAGE hWidget:NAME 
                VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
        
        hWidget = hWidget:NEXT-SIBLING .
    END.

    hFrame = hFrame:NEXT-SIBLING . 
END.
```

If there are nested frames, you'll have to implement a recursive call based on hWidget:TYPE = "FRAME" in the inner loop.

Comment: The above code shows error at  "ASSIGN hFrame      = {&window-name}:FIRST-CHILD ." . It can not understand after hFrame .

Comment: {&window-name} is valid when your program was developed in the AppBuilder. If that's not the case, you need to replace {&window-name} with the variable holding the handle of your window widget.